# Ada: How to print Enumerations as Lowercase

Tags: enumeration, ada

I have names starting with uppercase letter then the rest lowercase. It only prints in all uppercase. How to print as I have it defined? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify `Lower_Case` for the `Type_Set` parameter when you call the relevant [`Put`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-10.html) procedure in your instance of `Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO`. Given these declarations,

```
type Name_Type is (Alice, Bob, Carl);
package Name_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO (Name_Type);
```

The following code prints "bob" on the console:

```
Name_IO.Put(Bob, Name_IO.Default_Width, Ada.Text_IO.Lower_Case);
```

> Can I do "Bob" instead of "bob"?

Yes; for example,

- Using [`Ada.Characters.Handling`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-3-2.html), the functions `To_Lower`, `To_Upper`, and `To_Basic` are available for both strings and characters, as shown [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_case#Ada).
- Using `Enumeration_IO` and [`Ada.Strings.Fixed`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-3.html), the following fragment prints "Bob".

  ```
  Upper : String(1 .. 8);
  Lower : String(1 .. 8);
  …
  Name_IO.Put(Upper, Bob, Ada.Text_IO.Upper_Case);
  Name_IO.Put(Lower, Bob, Ada.Text_IO.Lower_Case);
  Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim(
     Upper(Upper'First) & Lower(Lower'First + 1 .. Lower'Last),
     Ada.Strings.Right));
  ```

Comment: can I do "Bob" instead of "bob"?

Comment: This doesn't work when you have unpredictable casing, like camel case.

Comment: @FinalArt2005: Right; you may have to adapt for a particular use case; sorry about the dead link; edited.